# Test with Lumen package

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, lumen

I develop lumen package and I don't know test this.

In my package, I use global method `config()` and `abort()` but this methods exist with `bootstrap/app.php` and I have'nt this file in my package.

I'm thinking redefine this methods with dummies class but I have to write only one test method in test class when I test a method with a changement in the config to can re-call an antoher `config` dummy class .

It's not practical and I guess there's better.

I can share code if you want.

--- Edit

This is example :

Class CheckAuthorizationTest

```
public function testCanSeeOtherUserRoles()
{
    $this->assertTrue(CheckAuthorization::canSeeOtherUserRoles($user, $user));
}
```

Class CheckAuthorization

```
static public function canSeeOtherUserRoles(Model $user_parent, Model $user_child)
{
    return self::roleIsParentOfDirectChild($user_parent, $user_child);
}

static public function canShowGroup(array $parent_group, string $child_group)
{
    $groupsHelper = new GroupsHelper();

    foreach ($parent_group as $group) {
        if (in_array($child_group, config('roles.roles'))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    abort(403);
}
```

Result :

There was 1 error:

```
1) ::testCanSeeOtherUserRoles
ReflectionException: Class config does not exist
```

Comment: Why do you need to use those functions to test? That seems counter intuitive. Unless of course you're testing that this package is installed in `Lumen` and not...`Yi` or something. In which case, you just need to add `Lumen` as a dependency.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question

Comment: You should define dummy data for your tests, not attempt to integrate it with production data.